# Android ActivityGroup back first activity on click

Tags: android, android-tabhost, tabactivity, activitygroup

I have an application with a TabActivity containing ActivityGroup. Each tabs works fine, but for one specific tab I want to go back to the first child activity when there's a click on it (whenever we are in a child activity of this tab or inside another tab).

I tried to start the activity that I want on the onResume of my ActivityGroup, it works when I'm on another tab, but not when I'm on this tab, with a child activity.

Do I have to use another intent flag than FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP for this tab ?
Does anyone have a clue ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usualy with ActivityGroup you have some kind of history.

Let's say your history is:

```
ArrayList<View> history;
```

Of course history needs to be initialized and have some Views in it which can be retrieved with:

```
getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(clazz.getName(), new Intent(this, clazz)).getDecorView();
```

where clazz is the class of your child Activity.
So on click in current ActivityGroup define a method like:

```
public void backToFirst() {
    int size = history.size();
    while (size > 1) {
        history.remove(size - 1);
        size = history.size();
    }
    setContentView(history.get(0));
}
```

Hope I understood you correctly and this is the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you. I hadn't answerd, but I had done that :
`code`
    public void resetChildActivities() {
  LocalActivityManager manager = getLocalActivityManager();
  int index = mIdList.size() - 1;

  for (int i = index; i > 0; i--) {
   manager.destroyActivity(mIdList.get(i), true);
   mIdList.remove(i);  
  }
 }

`code`
but your solution seams nicer.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi everyone  . iam new to android development .my requirement is i am facing one issue and unable to resolve it can anyone have a l ook onto it and help me in resolving the issue this is the l ink where i posted my code with logcats as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15223444/current-acivity-should-replaced-with-previous-activity-back